# Keyboard icon on Unity panel dissapeared

Tags: unity, keyboard, panel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where is the UIM notification area icon in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80104/where-is-the-uim-notification-area-icon-in-unity)

I've noticed that I don't have a keyboard layout icon on unity panel. There are 3 layouts configured, but I can't change between them, not even with defined keyboard shortcuts. How to solve this issue and how to get the icon back to the panel?
Ubuntu 11.10/Unity

Answer (score -1):

Keyboard Layout is available with "System Settings" and that is the icon that appears in the launcher even if Keyboard Layout is directly executed from Dash. System Settings is always available under the Gear icon in the upper right of your screen. You can chose to have System Settings available from the launcher by right clicking the icon when it's running and selecting "Keep in launcher".